# How to draw tangent and normal line to a circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw a tangent and normal line to the circle like the image below:

[image]

My written coding is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (c) at  (2,2) {$c$};
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (P) at (3,3.2);
    \draw[->,thick] (-1,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-1)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$};
    \draw (O) node [below left]{$0$};
    \draw (2, 2) circle[radius = 1.5cm];
    \foreach \i in {45}{
        \draw (2, 2) --++ (\i:1.5cm);
    }

    \draw [fill=black] (A) circle (1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

which produces.

[image]

Anyone, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a circle this is very easy.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,font=\sffamily]
    \path (2,2) coordinate[label=below:$c$](c);
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (P) at (3,3.2);
    \draw[->,thick] (-1,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-1)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$};
    \draw (O) node [below left]{$0$};
    \draw (c) circle[radius = 1.5cm];
    \foreach \i [count=\X] in {45}{
        \draw (c) --++ (\i:1.5cm) coordinate (x\X);
        \draw (x\X) -- ++ (\i:1) node[pos=0.8,below right]{normal}; % normal
        \draw (x\X) ++ (\i+90:1) -- ++ (\i-90:2)
        node[pos=0.9,above right]{tangent}; % tangent
    }

    \draw [fill=black] (c) circle (1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that Ti*k*Z offers many more options such as `tangent cs:`, see section **13.2.4 Tangent Coordinate Systems** of the pgfmanual v3.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

To draw normal to line `(p1)--(p2)` at point `(p1)`,

```
\draw ($(p1)!1!-90:(p2)$) -- ($(p1)!1!90:(p2)$);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (c) at  (2,2) {$c$};
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (P) at (3,3.2);
    \draw[->,thick] (-1,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-1)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$};
    \draw (O) node [below left]{$0$};
    \draw (2, 2) circle[radius = 1.5cm];
    \foreach \i in {45}{
        \draw (2, 2) --++ (\i:1.5cm)coordinate(p\i){};
        \draw ($(p\i)!1!-90:(2,2)$) -- ($(p\i)!1!90:(2,2)$);
    }

    \draw [fill=black] (A) circle (1pt);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```